# Retrieving RDS tags using boto3 gives an index error.

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-rds

I am trying to retrieve a tags using boto3 but I constantly run into the ListIndex out of range error.

My Code:

```
rds = boto3.client('rds',region_name='us-east-1')
rdsinstances = rds.describe_db_instances()
for rdsins in rdsinstances['DBInstances']:
        rdsname = rdsins['DBInstanceIdentifier']
        arn = "arn:aws:rds:%s:%s:db:%s"%(reg,account_id,rdsname)
        rdstags = rds.list_tags_for_resource(ResourceName=arn)            
        if 'MyTag' in rdstags['TagList'][0]['Key']:
            print "Tags exist and the value is:%s"%rdstags['TagList'][0]['Value']
```

The error that I have is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rdstags.py", line 49, in <module>
    if 'MyTag' in rdstags['TagList'][0]['Key']:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I also tried using the for loop by specifying the range, it didn't seem to work either.

```
for i in range(0,10):
   print rdstags['TagList'][i]['Key']
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate over list of tags first and compare `MyTag` with each item independently:
something like that:

```
 if 'MyTag' in [tag['Key'] for tag in rdstags['TagList']]:
     print "Tags exist and.........."
```

or better:

```
for tag in rdstags['TagList']:
    if tag['Key'] == 'MyTag':
        print "......"
```

Comment: Or better: 
`[tag['Value'] for tag in tags['TagList'] if tag['Key'] == 'MyKey][0]`

Answer (score 1):

I use function have_tag to find tag in all modul in Boto3

```
client = boto3.client('rds')
instances = client.describe_db_instances()['DBInstances']
if instances:
    for i in instances:
        arn = i['DBInstanceArn']
        # arn:aws:rds:ap-southeast-1::db:mydbrafalmarguzewicz
        tags = client.list_tags_for_resource(ResourceName=arn)['TagList']
        print(have_tag('MyTag'))
        print(tags)
```

Function search tags:

```
def have_tag(self, dictionary: dict, tag_key: str):
    """Search tag key
    """
    tags = (tag_key.capitalize(), tag_key.lower())
    if dictionary is not None:
        dict_with_owner_key = [tag for tag in dictionary if tag["Key"] in tags]
        if dict_with_owner_key:
            return dict_with_owner_key[0]['Value']
    return None
```